# Android installation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator, android-widget

I am a newbie in android. For installing android, i used the link:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Under the "**Troubleshooting ADT Installation**" section of the above link, there is an ADT-17.0.0.zip file avilable for download. I downloaded that file and from Eclipse ==> Install softwares i referred to that zip file and finally it got installed. It is working fine as well.

But now i am not able to understand how to start with sqlite in android for the database connectivity. I cant find any android folder created under "C:\Program Files", hence i am pretty much confused by the results displayed in a simple google search for getting started with Sqlite. Please someone guide me through how to get started with sqlite and from where to download the Sqlite. I am not able to proceed further at all. Please help.

Regards,
Bunta

Comment: did u download the android sdk?

Comment: No, i did not downloaded anything other than the ADT.zip file from the troubleshooting section of the link i mentioned above. May be that the sdk is downloaded automatically once i refer the zip file in my eclipse IDE. I am able to run all the basic programs related to button, spinner, etc and the emulator is also working fine. But the problem is i cant find any entry of android under my "Program files"........don't know why :( May be because its installed only in my Eclipse, hence not present there. Please suggest me a way to get started with Sqlite.  Ask if you want some more/other info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the sdk installed correctly by following the directions here:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html
```

The sdk comes bundled with sqlite3. Add the sdk directory to your path, this is what the Android site recommends for Windows:

> Adding both tools/ and platform-tools/ to your PATH lets you run command line tools without needing     to supply the full path to the tool directories. Depending on your operating system, you can include these directories in your PATH in the following way:
>
> On Windows, right-click on My Computer, and select Properties. Under the Advanced tab, hit the Environment Variables button, and in the dialog that comes up, double-click on Path (under System Variables). Add the full path to the tools/ and platform-tools/ directories to the path.

Once you have installed the sdk and started an emulator you can try:

```
adb shell
```

then go to the location of the database.

```
data/data/(YOURAPPNAME)/databases
```

type:

```
sqlite3 NAMEOFTHEDBFILE
```

This will give you direct access to the db file that was created and you can run queries etc. Directly on the db.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Rymnel,

Thanks for the reply. But where to find the database and where to run the command? Please read my 1st post, the way i installed Android for my Eclipse IDE, i am not able to find any Android folder under "Program files" or somewhere else in my local system. Please help, i am pretty much new and confused as well.
Regards,
bunty

Comment: Ah please follow the directions here. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: Once the emulator is started, where to type this command:

adb shell

Is there any cmd prompt for this or, u want me to do this somewhere else?

May be you feel this meaningkess, but cant help since i dont have any idea. Please help

Comment: the easiest way would be to go to the folder wherever the sdk was installed.  /SDKPATH/platform-tools/.  There is where you should type adb shell.  Alternatively, and probably a better long term option, would be to add this to your system path.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: I am extremely sorry sir for asking you so many questions :(

As i said in my 1st post, i can't find any sdk installed under my "Program files". Then where t find the adb shell? Please help me out. 

Thanks a lot again for the help

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell you where you installed the sdk.  Try and search for adb or platform-tools or something related to the sdk.

Comment: i installed the sdk by referring the eclipse ide to the adt zip folder. I cant see any android related entry in my program files folder or inside the control panel add or remove programs as well .I think the sdk is installed in the eclipse ide itself(though not sure). Is nt there some other alternative to find out the adb shell?

Comment: @BuntyBunta, Sounds like you don't have the sdk fully installed.  Please go back through the instructions for installing the sdk.

Comment: Thanks for all the info Rymnel. I found out where the sdk is installed and the tips you provided are working great. Thanks for the help again :)

Answer (score 1):

When you intend to develop sqlite using apps, sqlite run either on your device or in your emulator.

You don't have to download sqlite. Just use the sqlite related classes.

Comment: Hi stefan,
Thanks for the info. I am a java developer, used only Oracle db as of now. So in this case, do i need to create the tables or insert some values only using the java code or i can create it directly using the db side as well? And how can i see the entries present in the db directly by opening the sqlite IDE? Please provide some info. I am pretty much new in this. Thanks, Bunta

Comment: Hi Bunta, in general your app need to be able to create, update and display the data in the App. You don't have other access to data on your android device.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to download sqlite like in other java applications. try using the sqlite database packages in android given here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: Hi Anurag,
In that case i can create the tables or insert values using the java code. But is it possible to look at the values or create new tables directly by opening the sqlite? and where can i get the sqlite IDE (i mean inside the emulator or device or whatever you say)?
Thanks for clearing my doubts a lot, i am strugglingwith this from some time back. Please hlp me out can clear all my confusions. Thanks, Bunta

Comment: Inside Eclipse while the emulator is running, go to Window -> Show View -> Other.. -> Android -> File Explorer and then data/data/(Search your App_name)/databases
now you will be able to see your created database(s).

or you can try this http://shinesudarsanan.in/view-sqlite-database-for-android-from-eclipse/ . i hope it helps.